# Converting PDFs to be viewed in any browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I currently use a PDF-to-Flash to allow for users to flip thru pages of uploaded PDFs. However, with so many using iPhones/iPads I would like to switch this to a solution which works with any browser.

The site is developed in Ruby on Rails and I have looked into using pdf-toolkit and rmagick to convert the PDFs to images but it's not enough since I want the pages to scale with the browser window - SVG is not an option since I need for it to work w/ IE6 ;)

Any ideas?

Thx,

G

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use http://docs.google.com/viewer ?

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html

It's really simple, and it isn't Flash (can serve iPhone users too :D). Just add this to the view:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=#{YOUR_PDF_URL}&embedded=true"
style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a digital publishing platform like the one from Zmags. It converts a PDF to Flash, but when viewed on mobile devices it transforms into a swipeable version. Loads fast too.

Comment: Thanks. I've considered doing either:

1. Convert to both SVG (for webkit and firefox browsers) and SWF (for IE etc) and display accordingly.
2. Convert to both SVG and VML (for display in IE).
3. Resize PNG/JPG dynamically using javascript to see how big the viewport is.

Any feedback for these options?